# How to run php script from jQuery - on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple PHP script that sits in the home directory of my webserver. I also have a button called "campausebtn". I want to simply click the button and then call the php file using jquery. I've read many posts on SO and it seems simple, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried the following script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#campausebtn").click(function(){

        alert("Paused Clicked!");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'camera_pause.php',
            success: function() {
                alert("Paused!");

            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

The "Paused Click" alert is working fine, so I know the jQuery and button are working. It just wond't run the script.

Please can someone help?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing what's going wrong. There are thousands of reasons an AJAX request could fail. Check the console in dev tools for any errors, and also check the network tab after making the request to see what it's state is

Comment: Check your php error log for errors.

Comment: What the PHP script should do? If there is any output, you have to read it and the process/display the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "camera_pause.php",
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg );
  });
```

otherwise read the documentation on it: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks! I had to use the full path, and that worked.